# Are there any benefits from partitioning an Oracle on the same hdd?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm looking for the solution to improve insert time for concurrent inserts. Will I get any benefits from Oracle partitioning not providing dedicated hardware for every partition?

Answer (score 3):

What is the bottleneck in your current insert process?  I'm guessing from the "high concurrency" in your question that you're talking about an OLTP app where there are a large number of single-row inserts rather than a small number of many-row inserts that would be common in a data warehouse.

In an OLTP scenario, it is relatively unlikely that partitioning will decrease the time required to do a single-row insert.  Assuming that you've already eliminated the obvious time wasters like triggers on the table, most of the insert overhead is likely to be index maintenance with a bit of I/O for the writes to the redo logs.  Partitioning likely wouldn't reduce any of these because in an OLTP environment you generally can't load into a staging table and do a partition exchange which would reduce the index maintenance costs.

Comment: I totally agree that the place to start is determining what the bottleneck is.  But assuming that the situation is that concurrent inserts are competing for hot blocks in either the table or the index, couldn't partitioning be a possible approach for dealing with that if new rows were directed to different partitions?

Comment: @Dave - If the problem is contention on a hot block, and assuming different sessions inserted into different partitions with different local indexes, partitioning the table would be beneficial.  Hash partitioning the index might also help.  On the other hand, a reverse key index might also be enough to resolve the contention problem.

Comment: Hi Justin, Dave. i'd like to implement list partitiong by uniformely distributed value in range say 1-100. In this case i hope to reduce concurrency be removing segment level resources contention. there are no indexes and triggers on the table. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like everything else, it depends.

Partitioning can reduce contention and eliminate hot blocks.  For example, imagine if you will, a transaction system.  If you partitioned by hash across some surrogate customer ID value, each index would be significantly smaller, and potentially less subject to contention and index root splits.

Another solution if you have concurrency problems is the use of reverse-key indexes against "one-legged" indexes - where an indexed sequence-populated column forces continue block-splits.  However, using reverse-key indexes prevents range scans from using the index, so beware.

It really depends on what Oracle wait events are part of your critical transaction path.  What you're waiting on will generally dictate what solution is appropriate.

So it could help.  It could also make the situation worse.  Without more information about what's adding wait time - if anything - the internet can't help solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, @Adam. So in theory it could help. That's good. Unfortunately, i don't know Oracle internals well enough to profile insert and check what is the bottleneck. I know only insert time metrics. Will be very appreciate, if you point to something useful. Thank you!

Comment: Well, using StatsPack should help at a macro-tuning level, and it's documented in the Oracle Performance and Tuning Guide.